# How to activate entry-mode with VBA on non-activex textbox inserted to worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, worksheet

I manually placed a non-activex textbox on the worksheet. If i assign it a macro, then clicking the textbox runs the macro as expected.

However, entry-mode does not get enabled on the textbox. How can the macro put the textbox into entry-mode?

Note, this is a textbox inserted from the Insert ribbon.

[image]

thx

Answer (score 0):

i discovered the answer shortly before posting the above question:

```
Sub Activate_Textbox()
          ' stuff to do before edit mode...
          ' ...

          ' get textbox name
          Dim sName As String
          sName = Application.Caller

          ' get textbox shape object
          Dim txtBox As Shape
          Set txtBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes(sName)

          ' enter edit mode (put cursor into textbox)
          txtBox.TextFrame2.TextRange.Select

          ' cleanup
          Set txtBox = Nothing
End Sub
```

Recommended to protect the sheet, else you'll see selection handles on the textbox when it has focus. And, if you protect the sheet, you'll want to unlock text, so you can type in it:

[image]